# Stopping Windows Mobile 6.5 tab reordering

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a C++ Visual Studio 2008 Windows Mobile 6.5 application that uses a tab control. I've noticed that depending on how careful you are with the stylus, when using the tab control you can accidentally re-order the tabs. It's difficult to do deliberately, but it's very easy to do when you're not trying. I assume this is a new "feature" of Windows Mobile 6.5 as it doesn't happen in Windows Mobile 6.1 with the same code.

Is there a window style or something I can set that will lock the tab order such that people don't accidentally re-arrange them?

Also, is there an MSDN page that describes this behavior and how it is supposed to work? I've looked, but have come up empty.

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is a feature of the WTL tab class I was using. I ended up subclassing it and removing the tab reordering feature.

-PaulH